# Can't get my For loop or Foreach loop past the first item on the list

Tags: c#, for-loop, unity-game-engine, foreach

I'm a beginner here and tried to search for solutions with no luck. I'm trying to to find the closest object by tag and with priority target tags. For some reason the loop won't go past the first item on the list. Here is what I have:

```
public string[] PriorityTargets;
public float Range;

public GameObject projectileTarget;

void LateUpdate()
{
    float distanceToTarget;
    Debug.Log(PriorityTargets.Length);

    for (int i = 0; i <= PriorityTargets.Length; i++)
    {
        Debug.Log(PriorityTargets[i]);
        Debug.Log(i);

        GameObject Target = FindClosestTarget(PriorityTargets[i]);
        if (Target)
        {
            distanceToTarget = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, Target.transform.position);
            if (distanceToTarget <= Range)
            {
                projectileTarget = Target;
                Debug.Log("About to Break");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Debugger shows:

- array.length 3
- i 0
- string  first item only

There are no objects in the scene with PriorityTargets[0] tag, so it should keep going and break on PriorityTargets[1].

Also, the console never shows "About to Break".

here is the FindClosestTarget code:

```
GameObject FindClosestTarget(string TargetTag)
{
    GameObject[] gos = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag(TargetTag);

    GameObject closest = null;
    float distance = Mathf.Infinity;
    Vector3 position = transform.position;
    foreach (GameObject go in gos)
    {
        Vector3 diff = go.transform.position - position;
        float curDistance = diff.sqrMagnitude;

        if (curDistance < distance)
        {
            closest = go;
            distance = curDistance;
        }
    }

    return closest;

}
```

After debugging in VisualStudio some of the exceptions i get are the following:

> UnityEngine.UnassignedReferenceException: The variable projectileTarget of gadgetProjectile has not been assigned.
>   You probably need to assign the projectileTarget variable of the gadgetProjectile script in the inspector.
>
> UnityEngine.UnassignedReferenceException: The variable projectileTarget of gadgetProjectile has not been assigned.
>   You probably need to assign the projectileTarget variable of the gadgetProjectile script in the inspector.

there are other exceptions, but i am not sure if they are relevant. The script works fine if there is a target with the first tag.

Comment: It is likely a mistake in your `FindClosestTarget` code. Include that function too in your question as a edit.

Comment: i don't know if it is the actual problem but  shouldn' it be `if (Target !=null)`

Comment: @Scott just added it thank.

Comment: @pero i believe that is is better to use if (Target) in Unity

Comment: If you are indeed not seeing the iterations on the 2nd/3rd array members, you might have an uncaught exception. Otherwise I'd expect the break message to appear. Did you try debugging it with your IDE?

Comment: I tried to debug in VisualStudio, but my results are that of a noob :) .. I posted some of the exceptions in the original post. If someone can try to replicate this issue I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Bit hard to replicate your entire Unity project. What we would need from you is a [mcve]. What I can suggest is you step through your code one line at a time until you find you bug

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for being patient with me and pushing me to find the solution.

after trying to replicate in an empty project I found the issue.

When referencing the Tags, make sure the tags that you use in PriorityTargets[] are actually defined in Unity.

Meaning, if you set
PriorityTarget[0] to a random name like "dfsdsfsd" and that name is not an existing Tag in your project the script wont work.

cheers